# Set number of lines to variable in awk

Tags: awk

I am experimenting with an awk script (an independent file).
I want it to process a text file which looks like this:

```
value1: n
value2: n
value3: n
value4: n
value5: n
value6: n
value7: n

value1: n
  :
```

The text file contains a lot of these blocks with 7 values in each of them. I want the awk script to print some of these values (name of the value and "n") into a new file or the commandline. I thought I'd process it with a while loop, which works with a variable set to the number of all lines. But I just cant get the total of all lines in the file into a variable. It seems I have to process every line and do something with it until the end of the file to get the total. But I'd like to have the total in a variable and then process it with the while loop which loops until the total is reached.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: If your question is really just "how can I know how many lines there are in total", maybe you could prune a lot of your task description which isn't related to that particular problem.

Comment: Can you not just use `wc -l` before processing and put the result in a variable

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Unfortunately not, since some values are not single words

Comment: `wc -l` counts lines, not words.

Comment: You don't need an explicit loop, awk will read all lines one by one until the EOF reached.

Comment: @valh Just a follow up. Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Not really, I changed the whole script to get the results I wanted, but didnt find a solution to this specific problem

Answer (score 1):

Where $1 is the input parameter to your script: myscript textfile.txt

```
count="`wc -l $1 | cut -d' ' -f1`"    
echo "Number of lines in $1 is $count"
```

Then do your awk command utilising $count as your line count

Edit: courtesy of  fedorqui

```
count="`wc -l <$1`"    
echo "Number of lines in $1 is $count"
```

Edit 2: (forgive my awk command it's not something that I use much)

```
count="`wc -l </etc/fstab`"
echo "Number of lines in /etc/fstab is $count"
awk '{print $0,"\t","\tLine ",NR," of ","'$count'";}' /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Note `wc -l < $1` will provide the number without the name of the file.

Comment: To add another option `awk -v cnt=$count '{print $0,"\t","\tLine ",NR," of ",cnt;}'` which avoid cutting the string

Answer (score 0):

Either do two passes over the file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { lines = NR; next }
    { ... this happens on the second pass, use lines as you wish ... }' file file
```

or read the lines into an array and process it in `END`:

```
awk '{ a[NR] = $0 }
    END { lines = NR; for(i=1; i<=lines; ++i) { line = a[i]; ... } }' file
```

The first consumes I/O, the second memory.

In more detail,

```
awk 'NR==FNR { count++; next }
    { print "Item " FNR " of " count ": " $0 }' file file
```

or similarly

```
awk '{ a[NR] = $0; }
    END { for (i=1; i<=NR; ++i) print "Item " i " of " NR ": " a[i] }' file
```

If you need the line count outside of Awk, you will need to print it and capture it from your script.  If you have an Awk script which performs something useful and produces the count as a side effect, you will want to print the line count to standard output, and take care that all other output is directed somewhere else.  Perhaps like this;

```
lines=$(awk '{ sum += $1; }
    END { print "Average: " sum/NR >"average.txt"; print NR }')
# Back in Bash
echo "Total of $lines processed, output in average.txt"
```

Comment: The first one unfortunately does not work. When I try to print $lines after that it just does nothing or print some words.

Comment: `lines` is an Awk variable, not a Bash variable. If you want a Bash script, ask about Bash scripting.

Comment: I meant print lines (I am used to bash scripting, awk is rather new for me sry). However this:
NR==FNR { lines = NR; next }
    { print lines }
doesnt put out  anything.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer already, you need to pass the input file name twice.